# why does gridview create two colums when gridview columns are bound in aspx page

Tags: gridview

I have declared a gridview in aspx page as follows:

```
<tr>
<td class="columnData"colspan="2"> 
<asp:GridView ID="grdDataView" runat="server">
<columns>                                     
<asp:boundfield datafield="divisionname" headertext="Division Name"/> 
<asp:boundfield datafield="designation" headertext="Designation"/> 
<asp:boundfield datafield="noofemployee" headertext="No of Employee"/>           
</columns>
</asp:GridView>
</td>
</tr>
```

I bound gridview in a button click as follows:

```
grdDataView.DataSource = dt;
grdDataView.DataBind();
```

where dt contains column name divisionname,designation and noofemployee. It shows me the following output
[image]

I need to avoid second group of column in black rectangular box. How this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the property "AutoGenerateColumns" to "false".

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdDataView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
```

or else it will generate the columns automatically along with the columns that you specify specifically in your code.